# how to make geofence work when app is not in foreground or it is killed?

Tags: android, intentservice, android-geofence, android-jobscheduler

I am working on an app where i have to implement a feature that when user enters a particular range or location with particular radius like in Geofence. Then it should send notification which is also in client app not FCM. I have tried multiple solution but its not working. since Android O . Background task limitation. How to implement this feature without Foreground otherwise it would seem annoying? Please If anyone have any idea Do reply. Thanks in Advance.

Code for Client

```
geofencingClient.addGeofences( geoFencingReq(location!!.latitude,location.longitude,name), geofencePendingIntent)
```

Pending Intent ->

```
val geofencePendingIntent: PendingIntent by lazy {
        val intent = Intent(contextt, GeofenceTransitionsIntentService::class.java)
        // We use FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT so that we get the same pending intent back when calling
        // addGeofences() and removeGeofences().
        PendingIntent.getService(contextt, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
    }
```

I have updated the code which i have used but it doesnt work still when app is killed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By registering the Geofence with the Google API they automatically also get called from the background. You can find it in `com.google.android.gms.location`.

`GeofencingClient.addGeofences(GeofencingRequest, PendingIntent)` is what you need.

Comment: Thanks For Your reply. I'll get back to you after checking this solution, Thanks, @AntonioVlasic

Comment: I have updated my question and added the code . it doesnt work.  @AntonioVlasic